# Setting an environment variable in Windows PowerShell

Tags: powershell, cmd

I am having trouble replicating this command from CMD 
`set APPDATA=D:\`.

The best equivalent I have is `Set-Variable -Name $env:APPDATA -Value D:\`. This does not work!

The full script is:

```
set APPDATA=D:\
start java -jar D:\.minecraft\minecraft.jar
```

This sets it so Java looks in `D:\` for `.minecraft` instead of `APPDATA`.

The full PowerShell version (which doesn't work right) is:

```
& Set-Variable -Name $env:APPDATA -Value D:\
& 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin\java.exe' -jar D:\.minecraft\Minecraft.jar
```

It still looks at the read-only version of `$env:APPDATA`. I don't see why it can't be changed in the running environment for the shell's session, like cmd and most *nix shells!

I'm sure there are more uses for this than **just** running Minecraft. :P

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, since the other question never mentions `Set-Variable` at all.

Comment: That's probably because `Set-Variable` is for setting PowerShell variables, *not* for setting environment variables.

Comment: The other question doesn't actually say that `Set-Variable` is not for environment variables in any of the answers, nor was it mentioned in the question. While the solution is similar, it is not a duplicate question.

Comment: While you're right about `Set-Variable`, it's sad that the question *how to set an env variable with PowerShell* has already been asked several times, and we don't have a canonical Q to link to

Comment: Related post - [Powershell Add System Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32730544/465053)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you use `Set-Variable` the `-Name` argument should *NOT* have the dollar sign ($).

```
# WRONG: Set's the variable using the name stored in ENV:APPDATA
Set-Variable -Name $env:APPDATA -Value D:\
```

Also, `Set-Variable` doesn't appear to work as expected with environment variables. I'm assuming this is because `Set-Variable` is specifically designed to work with `Variable:` variable provider, rather than the `env:` environment provider. (I verified this locally, using `Set-Variable -Name ENV:AppData -Value "foo"` created a variable called 'ENV:AppData' in the `Variable:` provider.)

**Alternative 1 (simple format):**

```
$ENV:AppData="D:\"
& 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin\java.exe' -jar D:\.minecraft\Minecraft.jar
```

**Alternative 2 (using C# API):**

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("APPDATA", "D:\")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I did look around some, but I couldn't find anything. I am fairly new to the Powershell and didn't know about the `Variable:` provider vs the `Environment` provider. I was starting to guess that there was a _local variable_ vs a _global environment variable_, but I couldn't find anything saying that on official documentation by Microsoft, or I wasn't looking in the right place.